# Как подключить библиотеку AChartEngine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

Всем доброго дня! Это вопрос будет крайне глупым для многих, но я ещё новичок, посему извиняюсь.

Мне необходимо подключить библиотеку AChartEngine к моему приложению, но я не могу найти информацию как это сделать. В одних гайдах пишут, что нужно что-то прописывать в gradle, в других, что нужно добавить библиотеку в libs.

1) Что прописывать? Как я понял нужен package библиотеки, однако на гитхабе https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine я его не нашёл.

2) Скачав файл библиотеки я внёс его в папку lib проекта, но студия его не видит.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто нибудь объяснит как в принципе добавлять библиотеки в проект, не только этот конкретный пример, или бросит толковый гайд.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014369/achartengine-and-android-studio

Comment: По ссылке в вопросе есть ссылка на туториал, где написано, как подключить.

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо! Не заметил сначала, что оно там есть. Но всётаки, где брать package чтобы прописать его в gradle? Или его должен сразу указывать разработчик библиотеки?

Comment: Обычно указывают.